# Longitudinal dataset: counting the number of repeats and storing the value in a variable

Tags: stata, longitudinal, long-format-data

I have a longitudinal/long layout dataset in Stata in which RecordIDs are repeated/ I want to generate a new variable which shows the number of times each ID is repeated. How can I write the code?

I tried:

```
bysort RecordID : gen repeat_no = _n
```

but I'm getting the serial number of the times of repeats.

I want a variable to store the total number of times each ID is repeated (like shown in the image).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2YVt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bysort RecordID : gen repeat_NO = _N
```

For documentation of these basic constructs, see e.g.

```
help _variables
```